# CSS3 box-shadow has no depth

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to apply CSS box-shadow to a header div, but for some reason rather than getting a box shadow with depth, all I get is a flat line. I've tried different colors, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Image: [image]

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header-wrapper">
      <div id="header">
           ......
      </div>
 </div>
 <div id="slider-wrapper">
       <div id="slider">
        .....
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 div#wrapper {
    position: relative;
 } 
 div#header-wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 125px;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f0f0f0));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f0f0f0); 
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f0f0f0);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f0f0f0);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f0f0f0);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 5px #c6c6c6;
  }
  div#slider-wrapper {  
    margin-top: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;  
   }
```

Comment: looks like something might be covering up the shadow, resulting in only seeing a little bit of it?

Comment: but shouldn't the z-index allow the shadow to go over the slider?

Comment: don't post a link to the actual problem, when it be solved the link will be useless for future visitors. Try to isolate the code that produces the problem and post it in jsfiddle

Comment: @MrLister, I place positioning in the main `wrapper` tag though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the shadow to fall over the image, you have to apply a z-index to the div that contains the image.

You already have a `z-index` property, but those work only on positioned elements.

Solution: add `position:relative` to `div#slider-wrapper`.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/HHAeT/1/).

Edit: The official reference is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index). It doesn't say *why* the element needs to be positioned though. Unpositioned elements have a stacking order too. If anybody can point me to a document describing the why, I'd love to know.